# If-else and error handing in command prompt

Tags: shell, powershell, cmd, rubygems, appveyor

I am trying to detect if certain ruby gem is not installed, install it first and then proceed.

For instance:

```
gem which rails
```

returns path to gem's driver file (`.rb`) on `stdout`, if gem exists, if not it checks throws error on `stderr`.

How can I solve it?

Pseudo code:

```
if throws "gem which example1" ( gem install example1 )
if throws "gem which example2" ( gem install example2 )
if throws "gem which example3" ( gem install example3 )

:: install other stuff
```

Either cmd or powershell would work.

I need to add these in AppVeyor CI yaml configuration file. AppVeyor CI has this wonderful feature of caching the directory for DRY'ing installations to improve build performance. So I have cached the gems directory and it restores fine on running the build, but then `gem install` reinstalls the gem anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using powershell to run the command you can use error redirection to check if the command was successful:

```
$gemPath = gem which example3 2>$null

if ($gemPath)
{
    # We got a path for the gem driver
}
else
{
    # Failed, gem might not be installed
}
```

Explanation: We're telling powershell to store the result of "gem which example3" in the variable `$gemPath`, however if there is an error we want to redirect the error to the variable `$null` by using `2>$null`

You can also replace 2 with the number corresponding to the stream you'd like to capture (Success, Error, Warning etc)

```
    *   All output
    1   Success output
    2   Errors
    3   Warning messages
    4   Verbose output
    5   Debug messages
```

More on redirection here [About_Redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much! I will just use `if(!gemPath) { gem install blah }`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try, in .cmd script:

```
gem which rails 1>nul 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (gem install rails)
```

I'm assuming here you want the outputs to `stdout` and `stderr` stifled for purposes of this batch script - otherwise, drop the `1>nul 2>&1`.

Comment: thank you. Actually dropping `1>nul 2>&1` will cause AppVeyor CI to throw error and mark the build job as failure. I was primarily looking for this solution. Both PowerShell and CMD solutions are equally useful on AppVeyor! :)